# How in Drupal to get a link from a field (Media->Document) in Paragraph?

Tags: drupal, twig

I have a Drupal paragraph with 3 fields:

The "File" field is a "Media" field with type "Document"

I'm trying to display values of these fields in .twig file of this paragraph:

```
{% block paragraph %}
    {% if paragraph.status.value %}
        Title: {{ paragraph.field_item_title.value }}<br>
        Description: {{ paragraph.field_item_description.value }}<br>
        URL: {{ paragraph.field_item_file.value }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

As a result Title and Description are output correctly, and nothing is output in URL, although I expected the output of a link to the file

I also tried this:

```
{{ paragraph.field_item_file.entity.url }} // nothing
{{ paragraph.field_item_file.entity.id }} // 3098
```

How do I get a link to download a file from the "File" field in .twig template?

Answer (score 0):

try the following to get the link of the document, this can be added as href value to make it downloadable

```
{{ file_url(paragraph.field_your_field.entity.field_media_document.entity.fileuri) }}
```

other values can be accessed in the same way just after `field_media_document.entity.`